# How can I automatically insert fuel into an Alchemical Furnace?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I have an enormous, golem-automated setup to feed crafting tables into a hungry node to power it up, but in order to keep the Automagy golem crafting tables running, I require Fabrico essence. I have an alchemical furnace that creates Fabrico from some of the crafting tables, and a golem feeding in more crafting tables, but I can't figure out how to feed fuel into the furnace. Both golems and hoppers just put things into the upper slot, instead of the fuel slot. Is there any way to load fuel into it?

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer from the Thaumcraft thread on the Minecraft forums. You can have golems place fuel in an alchemical furnace by marking the bottom side of the furnace with the golem bell. The golem doesn't have to be able to actually access the bottom side, fuel can be inserted from any side, but the bottom has to be the marked side.